# CSS - equivalent of "nth-child" for "start" when start is not 1

Tags: html, css

In a situation where one has a list with a series of questions that start at 0, is it possible to apply css in relation to its affected value? For example, if a list were as such...

```html
<b>How do you feel?</b>
<ol start="0">
    <li>Great</li>
    <li>Good</li>
    <li>Fine</li>
    <li>I do not understand the question</li>
</ol>
```

....Is there a valid equivalent of this pseudocode?

```css
ol li {
    color: rgb (180, 180, 180);
}

ol li:value-of-child(2) {
    color: rgb (0, 0, 0);
}
```

Such that it would appear in this way:

[image: by value instead of nth-child]

I've tried to use the following, but it did not work.

```css
ol li {
    color: rgb (180, 180, 180);
}

ol li:nth-child(calc(my_value - 1)) {
    color: rgb (0, 0, 0); 
}
```

`my_value` is inserted after the user makes a selection in a separate textfield, by a completely different application, and I am unable to use JavaScript to solve this problem. *(I know this begs a lot of questions -- believe me, ideally I would never do it this way, but unfortunately I have pretty limited control over the kind of document I'm working with).*

**UPDATE:** I had hoped to not try and get into too much of why I'm so restricted, but it would appear that people are treating it as an XY problem and that just isn't the case.

I'm working with an app that doesn't use weblang things on the front-end, but it *produces* a document that's displayed using WebKit. Its output can be affected by html/css -- **but cannot employ JavaScript at any stage** because the document must be human readable if it is being viewed as plain text. Additionally, my employer is not keen on establishing the precedent for permitting JS to infiltrate our common practices -- the bulk of employees here are trained to use our application, not JavaScript -- so even if it weren't an effectual issue it would still be verboten as a matter of maintaining my employment. :)

The actual list as seen above is separate from the user's method of input. (The lists we use have a character limit; as such, by necessity, selections longer than "some upper limit" are truncated, so most of the actual entries wouldn't fit.) Therefore, below each list as displayed, there is a popup menu that offers selections numbered 0 - 3. The user's selection will appear on the narrative, as many times as I like, which is why I can try and use that value to affect CSS vis-a-vis something like an `nth-child` selector.

In *this* instance, the list numbers start with 0 because whomever wrote the test decided that scores range from 0 to 3. So I can't just bump everything up 1 unit; it's not my material to modify, just reproduce.

What I *can* do is affect the kind of HTML being generated on the document (again, not to alter the elements/widgets on the *interactive* side, just the *narrative* side) and use CSS to affect the output. So, at the very least, when the document is viewed as intended the answer can be displayed while also greying out the answer they actually selected, instead of having a very redundant document which reads...

**Is This Awesome?**

0. Yes
1. No
2. Maybe
3. Eli Whitney

**Answer: 3**

**Okay, What About This?**

0. Kinda
1. Kinda Not
2. Never
3. Supernever

**Answer: 2**

...and so on.

A careful reader might stop me here -- because if JavaScript isn't allowed because of the plain text factor, why bother with CSS? You're not wrong, this wouldn't affect a plain text version of the document, but it is "as much as I can do" to try and make the narrative display a little easier to read when viewed in-app, or when printed to a PDF.

I really have a pretty limited range of things which I can directly affect as it pertains to the generated document, so I was hoping for a means of at least making the narrative output a little cleaner.

Comment: css doesn't care what the human-readable number is. it's dealing with the internal array/list that presents those `<li>` elements, and those are always numbered `0,1,2,etc...`

Comment: If you cannot use javascript, why not use radio buttons instead?

Comment: I'm very very limited with the kinds of markup that I get to work with. Believe me, I would love to rip up the HTML and craft something different. I have to pretty much deal with what I'm given

Comment: Anyway, do the list items themselves have values? Is the markup something like `<li value="0">`? If so, you could simply use `li[value='myvalue']` as the selector.

Comment: I think you need to take another look at the question as written, because - and this could be entirely down to me - I'm struggling to understand the nature of the problem. What's the starting HTML, what does the JavaScript do, or add, to change that HTML? What result are you looking for?

Comment: Furthering @MrLister comment: how exactly *is* `my_value` being inserted into the markup? As an attribute on the `<li>`?

Comment: @DavidThomas the starting HTML was actually in the OP's question. I formatted it properly as a code block. The result they're looking for is in the screenshot.

Comment: To be honest, isn't the `start` attribute irrelevant here? It changes the counting number of the ol, but that is only superficial - in JS you are still dealing with items ordered from 0-whatever, in CSS you are still dealing with `:nth-child(0)` to whatever, unrelated to what the actual number that is displayed is. Why is this necessary?

Comment: @Stick How/Where/When do you change the "my_value" with the existing code?

Comment: That's the problem, is *I* don't change my_value at all. I know this seems like an XY problem, but really after I update the description it will become clear that I am locked into a rather odd situation that doesn't make a non-CSS solution really possible.

Comment: @Stick Updated my answer with hopefully something valueable

Comment: @Stick Did my answer bring any valueable help?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Could this be something you could use?</strike>

**Edit:**

Below sample shows a possible logic that you might could use. For me to be more specific, I need to see the html code you can render, to better understand if there is some other solutions.

```css
ol > li {
  color: #BBB;
}
.qiz {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;    /* make space for the answer */
}                               
.qiz > div[data-value] {
  position: absolute;      /* put answer at bottom, visiually, but it has to be */
  bottom: 0;               /* before in DOM as there is no "parent" selector  */
}

/* qiz nr1, qiz nr2 */
.qiz > div[data-value="1"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(1)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="2"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(2)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="3"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(3)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="4"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(4)  {
  color: #000;
}

/* qiz nr3 */
.qiz > div[data-value="5"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(1)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="6"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(2)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="7"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(3)  {
  color: #000;
}
.qiz > div[data-value="8"] ~ ol > li:nth-child(4)  {
  color: #000;
}

/* qiz nr4 - using normal flow and data-value is set on the ol tag */
.qiz > ol[data-value="1"] > li:nth-child(1) {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="qiz nr1">
  Is This Awesome?
  <div data-value="3">Answer: 3</div>
  <ol start="0">
    <li>Yes</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>Maybe</li>
    <li>Eli Whitney</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="qiz nr2">
  Okay, What About This?
  <div data-value="2">Answer: 2</div>
  <ol start="5">
    <li>Kinda</li>
    <li>Kinda Not</li>
    <li>Never</li>
    <li>Supernever</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="qiz nr3">
  If you need it like this?
  <div data-value="8">Answer: 8</div>
  <ol start="5">
    <li>Dont Know</li>
    <li>Hopefully Not</li>
    <li>Maybe ...</li>
    <li>Doh, YES</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="qiz nr4">
  Using normal element flow?
  <ol start="0" data-value="1">
    <li>This is selected</li>
    <li>But this not</li>
    <li>Neither this</li>
    <li>Not the last either</li>
  </ol>
  <div>Answer: 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

With a bit of puzzling, I found an answer, with the caveat that it only works if you know how many items there are in the list. In this example, there are 6 items (0 to 5) so you'll write `6n-my_value`, which the platform will then translate to `6n-2` if my_value is 2.

This probably means you'll have to have different CSS for different OLs.

```css
ol > li {
  color: #BBB;
}
ol > li:nth-last-child(6n-2) { /* or in your stylesheet: 6n-my_value */
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ol start="0">
  <li>Great</li>
  <li>Good</li>
  <li>Fine</li>
  <li>Bad</li>
  <li>None of your business</li>
  <li>I do not understand the question</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: To the downvoter: I removed the possibly offending bits in the answer; is this better? Edit: apparently not.